# AWS ELB dropping the connections. Need to keep it alive

Tags: amazon-web-services, vertica

I have my AWS deployment of SpringBoot application which fires select queries (based on request) and generates an output file (zip) containing the resultset.
The communication is:

```
SpringBoot app -> AWS Route 53 -> AWS ELB -> Vertica DB Cluster
```

The queries fired can run for hours, and thus, my connection is to be kept alive. The problem is ELB seems to drop the connection after the idle-timeout period. The application connects to Vertica DB on port 5433.

```
[root@ip-10-122-5-151 logs]# netstat -anpo | grep 5433
tcp6       0      0 10.122.5.151:47956      10.122.32.89:5433       ESTABLISHED 26605/java           keepalive (9.06/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.122.5.151:58416      10.122.33.133:5433      ESTABLISHED 26605/java           keepalive (8.67/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.122.5.151:47966      10.122.32.89:5433       ESTABLISHED 26605/java           keepalive (11.10/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.122.5.151:47972      10.122.32.89:5433       ESTABLISHED 26605/java           keepalive (12.38/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.122.5.151:47960      10.122.32.89:5433       ESTABLISHED 26605/java           keepalive (10.08/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.122.5.151:47970      10.122.32.89:5433       ESTABLISHED 26605/java           keepalive (12.13/0/0)
```

As can be seen, client has the keep-alive. On the Vertica cluster, we have set up the properties:

```
echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
echo 20 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
```

[(Source)](https://www.vertica.com/blog/configuring-tcp-idle-settings-long-running-idle-sessions/)

Our ELB timeout is set to 80 seconds for now.

*Note: we have set low values for now to test the issue*

However, when I run any query, it returns an EOFException after 80 seconds (which is due to the connection close). I have also tested this from the DB clients by running 
**SELECT SLEEP(90);**

Is there any way for me to keep this connection alive for a few (4-6) hours?

Comment: I don't think so you can increase the timeout for more than 4000 seconds (MAX). However, you can explore option of putting your select queries into a caching layer of memcached, possibly Redis, etc)

Comment: I don't expect AWS to increase the timeout (from current 4000; wouldn't complain if they do though), but some way to ensure connection is kept alive. Memcache wouldn't be a fit for our need though.

Comment: @Pankaj increase the timeout is in effect exactly what you are asking for.  Despite your settings, the connection is *still idle* at the higher layers so the *idle timeout* is firing.  TCP keepalives don't increment payload byte counters, and that is the type of "idle" under consideration.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I get what you are saying, and yes, after reading the docs thoroughly, I understand why you are right. Alternatively, we have found a couple of ways to resolve this for our use-case, one of them works, other we are yet to try. Will update here once we confirm it (though it will take some time being the year-end). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this post with similar problem, we have now addressed it.
The problem is that ELB does not honor TCP parameters (tcp keep-alives).

There were a couple of ways to address this:

1. Eliminate ELB, and instead use EIPs for the DB cluster.
2. Replace ELB with NLB.

We went ahead with NLB as that seemed like the ideal solution for us. However, if you still have issues with NLB, do read on the restrictions it brings in when connecting via it (Ex. You need nitro instances on the client side to connect to NLB with intra-vpc connections etc.)

Comment: Do you have any source to back up the claim that the ELB doesn't honor TCP keep-alives? Would appreciate confirmation that the issue exists since we're getting weird unexpected connection drops that should be before the idle timeout period.